# How much time does it take bodies to change their current state of motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, mass, acceleration, time

Correct me if I’m wrong in any of this

bodies with mass tend to resist any change in their state of motion .. if they are at rest .. they resist motion and if they are in motion they resist being put to rest
Still .. there is this question that has been bothering me for a while ..
How much time does it take bodies subject to change in their state of motion to actually change their state of motion? Is it instantly? If so .. how come there is resistance .. resistance means they don’t change their state of motion instantly.. so there must be a duration of time through which they are in a transitioning state .. if so .. what is that time? all bodies seem to have the same time (again correct me if I’m wrong .. still what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "state of motion" is *velocity*, the rate of change of position with respect to time.

A the change in velocity with respect to time is *acceleration*.

The mathematical representation of the law you are referencing is:

$F=ma$, where $F$ is force, $m$ is mass, $a$ is acceleration.

If $F$ and $m$ are constant, we can express $a = \Delta v/ \Delta t$, the total change in velocity divided by the total change in time. Then we can solve

$F = m \Delta v/ \Delta t$

and obtain

$\Delta t = m \Delta v/F$

Or in words: the amount of time it takes for an object of mass m to change from one velocity to another, equals the mass of the object, multiplied by the difference between the velocities, divided by the force applied to the object.

Force is the quantity that the compression of an ideal spring measures. A bathroom scale measures force.